# Appending saved ICACLS settings in a loop from file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, icacls

Assuming list of files or folders in C:\temp\listoffolders.txt

```
for /f eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %a in (C:\temp\listoffolders.txt) do cmd.exe /c icacls "%a" /save C:\temp\listoffolders.txt\iCACLSBackup.txt
```

The output is perfect... but the issue I need to overcome is appending data to the save file rather than overwriting...

Answer (score 0):

Use a compound command to save the ACLs into a temporary file and append the temporary file to a consolidated file:

```
@echo off
::
:: Reads pathnames from the file listoffiles.txt and saves the
:: corresponding ACLs in listofacls.txt
::
set TEMPFILE=tmp%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.txt
if exist listofacls.txt del listofacls.txt
for /f "delims="" eol=""" %%f in (listoffiles.txt) do (
  echo "%%f"
  icacls "%%f" /save %TEMPFILE% >nul
  type %TEMPFILE% >>listofacls.txt
)
del %TEMPFILE%
```

(This is a rough-and-ready script. In production you would want to add a modicum of error checking, place the temporary files in %TEMP% and so on.)

What to do with the consolidated file is another question. Note that `icacls` saves the ACLs in a file using UTF-16 little-endian encoding -- there will be plenty of null bytes in there.

Comment: that provides an invalid parameter for each item:
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Policy Platform\policyHost.exe" /service
Invalid parameter "Files\Microsoft"
it does create the listofacls.txt file but it is blank

Comment: @thatotheritguy: What is in your file containing the list of files? I have tested this script using the direct output from `dir /b`. And where does `/service` come from? Anyway, the script was intended just to show the technique -- write the ACLs for each file in a temporary file, then use `type >>` to append that file to the master file.

Comment: The original file is generated via wmic call 
`for /f "tokens=2 delims='='" %a in ('wmic service list full^|find /i "pathname"^|find /i /v "system32"') do @echo %a >> c:\windows\temp\listoffolders.txt`
So, the exe is listed as well as the service call if it exists

Comment: Have you tried looking into that file with a hex editor? It's not a nice text file. It contains <CR>s not followed by <LF> and stray spaces.

Comment: Which is what I thought I was getting around with the eol and delims statements

`eol^=^"^ delims^=^"`

Comment: Found that I could use the following code to iterate through and then concatenate results using copy command
     `for /f eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %a in (c:\windows\temp\permissions.txt) do cmd.exe /c icacls "%a" /save "c:\windows\temp\%~na_ServiceBackup.txt"
`
it is a bit clumsy, but functional...

Answer (score 0):

Let your command line write into a temporary file (e. g., `C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp`), then use the following to append the content to your final target file (`C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.txt`):

```cmd
copy /Y /B "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.txt"+"C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp" "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.txt"
```

Clean up the temporary file afterwards:

```cmd
del "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp"
```

You can use all that even in a single command line:

```cmd
(for /F usebackq^ eol^=^"^ delims^=^" %a in ("C:\temp\listoffolders.txt") do icacls "%~a" /SAVE "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp") && copy /Y /B "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.txt"+"C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp" "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.txt" && del "C:\temp\iCACLSBackup.tmp"
```

The `&&` operator executes the following command only in case the previous one succeeded, that is, when its exit code is zero.

I omitted the `cmd /C` part as I believe it is not necessary.